# Getting incorrect Syntax Error In Stored Procedure with CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I am trying to create a stored proc where I need to find all the latest entries of a given dealer number and then get the total count according to some conditions. I have created it like this:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNotificationCount] @DealerNumber varchar(50),
                                              @NotificationCount int OUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @UserId varchar(50);
    WITH Notifications (RequestId, StatusId, RequestStatusId, UserId, row_num) AS
        (SELECT r.ID,
                rs.StatusID,
                rs.ID,
                r.UserID,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.Id, rs.StatusID ORDER BY DateTimeStamp DESC) AS row_num
         FROM Requests r
              INNER JOIN RequestStatuses rs ON r.ID = rs.RequestID
         WHERE r.DealerNumber = @DealerNumber)
    Set @UserId = (Select Top 1 UserId from Requests where DealerNumber = @DealerNumber)
    SELECT @NotificationCount = COUNT(*)
    FROM Notifications n
         INNER JOIN Statuses s ON n.StatusId = s.ID
    WHERE n.row_num = 1
      AND n.StatusId IN (SELECT ID FROM Statuses WHERE DealerPortal = 'Additional Info Needed')
      AND n.RequestStatusId NOT IN (SELECT RequestStatusId FROM AdditionalInfoViewed WHERE UserId = @UserId);
END;
```

But I am getting compile time error

> Incorrect Syntax near SET statement.

I am not sure where I am doing wrong. Please suggest.

Comment: your `CTE` `Notifications ` is at the wrong lines. It should be just before the line `select @NotificationCount = Count(*)`. Which means the line `Set @UserId = ...` should goes before the `CTE`

Comment: Whitespace and Linebreaks are paramount to making readable text; not just in code. Please get into the habit of making good use of both. Poor/bad formatting is not going to help you or others when you need to be able to quickly read and understand your code. It helps easily distinguish specific code blocks, and sections, and also makes finding errors far easier when a line only contains 10's of characters, rather than 100's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set @UserId  value before cte begins( before "with" keyword )

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNotificationCount]
@DealerNumber varchar(50),
@NotificationCount int out
AS
BEGIN
Declare @UserId varchar(50);
Set @UserId = (Select Top 1 UserId from Requests where DealerNumber = @DealerNumber)
;With Notifications (RequestId, StatusId, RequestStatusId, UserId, row_num)
AS
(
select r.ID, rs.StatusID, rs.ID, r.UserID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.Id,rs.StatusID ORDER BY DateTimeStamp DESC) as row_num
 from Requests r inner join RequestStatuses rs on r.ID = rs.RequestID
 where  r.DealerNumber = @DealerNumber

)
select @NotificationCount = Count(*) from Notifications n inner join  Statuses s
on n.StatusId = s.ID
Where n.row_num = 1 and n.StatusId in (Select ID from Statuses where DealerPortal = 
'Additional Info Needed') 
and n.RequestStatusId not in (select RequestStatusId from AdditionalInfoViewed where 
UserId = @UserId)
END
```

Comment: I tried that.. but then I am getting run time error: "Incorret Syntax near @NotificationCount"

Comment: @ƏşrəfCəfərli,  `Set @UserId = (Select Top 1 UserId from Requests where DealerNumber = @DealerNumber);`

Comment: *"use ";" with "with" keyword, for example ;"* Don't do that... [The semicolon (`;`) is a statement terminator](https://wp.larnu.uk/fundamentals-the-semicolon-is-a-statement-terminator/) *not* a "beginningator". It goes at the *end* of **all** your statements, not at the start of statements that require the **previous** statement to be properly terminated. Not terminating your statements properly is deprecated, so you should really try to get into the habit of properly terminating your statements now, so that your code doesn't break if the change is every forced through.

Answer (score 1):

It's not allowed to use set variables in a CTE, you should `SELECT` variables as same rules as `VIEW` are in place or populate the variables outside the CTE

```
SELECT @UserId = ....
```

should work

Rules for variables in a common table expression: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)